# SP2013 Send to connections feature. Setting URL of document in final location

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

We setup the Send to Connections feature in SharePoint 2013 to send Sharepoint document to an external system.  The send functionality is successful and returns the following page.

```
Home : Operation Completed Successfully
The file has been sent to the "XXXXXXXX" location successfully.
URL to find or request access to the document in its final location:
```

[image: Success Page Screenshot]

Is there a way to specify the URL of the final location in the SubmitFile method return value?  The current implementation returns the string.

```
<ResultCode>Success</ResultCode>
```

Is there a way to hide the "URL to find or request access to the document in its final location" prompt from this page?